# Django - Admin - Mandatory Inlines

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible configure Mandatory Inlines in Django Admin Site?

For example, Student page has Address as a inline. Each Student should have at least one address selected from Inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inline Form Validation in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877723/inline-form-validation-in-django)

Comment: Is it possible to make the same with extra = 0?

Answer (score 1):

From Django 1.7 you can use `min_num`.