# Validation of dependant inlines in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.4 and I want to set validation rules that compare values of different inlines.

I have three simple classes

In models.py:

```
class Shopping(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    item_shop = models.ForeignKey(Shopping)

class Buyer(models.Model):
    buyer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    buyer_shop = models.ForeignKey(Shopping)
```

In admin.py:

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item

class BuyerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Buyer

class ShoppingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ItemInline, BuyerInline)
```

So for example it is possible to buy a bottle of rhum at 10$ and one of vodka at 8$. Mike pays 15$ and Tom pays 3$.

The goal is to prevent the user from saving an instance with sums that don't match: what has been paid must be the same as the sum of the item costs (ie 10+8 = 15+3).

I tried:

- raising ValidationError in the Shopping.clean method. But the inlines aren't updated yet in clean so the sums are not correct
- raising ValidationError in the ShoppingAdmin.save_related method. But raising ValidationError here gives a very user unfriendly error page instead of redirecting to the change page with a nice error message.

Is there any solution to this problem? Is client-side (javascript/ajax) validation the most simple?

Comment: hello, have you come up with something for this? I face the exact same problem. The only solution I can think of is the inline model's clean method, but this would produce a big db overhead.

Comment: I guess one solution is to edit django admin's behavior. Look at django/contrib/admin/options.py, the add_view method line 924

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could override your Inline formset to achieve what you want. In the clean method of the formset you have access to your Shopping instance through the 'instance' member. Therefore you could use the Shopping model to store the calculated total temporarily and make your formsets communicate. In models.py:

```
class Shopping(models.Model):
   shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       super(Shopping, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.__total__ = None
```

in admin.py:

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet
class ItemInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
   def clean(self):
      super(ItemInlineFormSet, self).clean()
      total = 0
      for form in self.forms:
         if not form.is_valid():
            return #other errors exist, so don't bother
         if form.cleaned_data and not form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE'):
            total += form.cleaned_data['cost']
      self.instance.__total__ = total


class BuyerInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
   def clean(self):
      super(BuyerInlineFormSet, self).clean()
      total = 0
      for form in self.forms:
         if not form.is_valid():
            return #other errors exist, so don't bother
         if form.cleaned_data and not form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE'):
            total += form.cleaned_data['cost']

      #compare only if Item inline forms were clean as well
      if self.instance.__total__ is not None and self.instance.__total__ != total:
         raise ValidationError('Oops!')

class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Item
   formset = ItemInlineFormSet

class BuyerInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Buyer
   formset = BuyerInlineFormSet
```

This is the only clean way you can do it (to the best of my knowledge) and everything is placed where it should be.

**EDIT:** Added the *if form.cleaned_data* check since forms contain empty inlines as well.
Please let me know how this works for you!

**EDIT2:** Added the check for forms about to be deleted, as correctly pointed out in the comments. These forms should not participate in the calculations.

Comment: Awesome! It's a shame I can't vote your answer up; I don't have enough reputation. Edit: NVM some reputation points magically appeared

Comment: It should disregard deleted rows with: ``if form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE'): continue``

Comment: This is a lovely strategy, thanks.  I have a problem, though, because when there are no inlines added, the error messages don't occur.  In my code, I have only one inline formset defined because I am comparing it to a field in the main model (so in the example above, in `BuyerInlineFormSet`, I would use the comparison `if self.instance.amount != total: raise ...`.  When I save the `Shopping` instance with an amount > 0 and without adding any `Buyers`, it tells me the form is valid, even though it is not (because the sum of no Buyer amounts is 0).

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you, I thought this wasn't possible after looking everywhere else. However, it's worth noting that this will only work as long as the `ItemInline` appears before the `BuyerInline` in the `inlines` list of the `ShoppingAdmin`, i.e. the `clean()` method of the Inline that appears first will run first, and this relies on this behaviour.

Comment: Great answer! Filtering out all the marked-for-deletion forms with `form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE')` is just awesome!

Answer (score -3):

Alright I have a solution. It involves editing django admin's code.

In django/contrib/admin/options.py, in the add_view (line 924) and change_view (line 1012) methods, spot this part:

```
        [...]
        if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
            self.save_model(request, new_object, form, True)
        [...]
```

and replace it with

```
        if not hasattr(self, 'clean_formsets') or self.clean_formsets(form, formsets):
            if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
                self.save_model(request, new_object, form, True)
```

Now in your ModelAdmin, you can do something like this

```
class ShoppingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ItemInline, BuyerInline)
    def clean_formsets(self, form, formsets):
        items_total = 0
        buyers_total = 0
        for formset in formsets:
            if formset.is_valid():
                if issubclass(formset.model, Item):
                    items_total += formset.cleaned_data[0]['cost']
                if issubclass(formset.model, Buyer):
                    buyers_total += formset.cleaned_data[0]['amount']

        if items_total != buyers_total:
            # This is the most ugly part :(
            if not form._errors.has_key(forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS):
                form._errors[forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS] = []
            form._errors[forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS].append('The totals don\'t match!')
            return False
        return True
```

This is more a hack than a proper solution though. Any improvement suggestions? Does anyone think this should be a feature request on django?

Comment: It's more of a hack indeed since we have to manually append the errors in the list rather than raising a ValidationError. But it still works though! I think this is basically a matter of formset validation. In that sense maybe one could create a custom FormSet class, implement a proper clean method and use that class instead of the default formset in the inline. Just a thought..

Comment: Do you suggest manually creating ONE FormSet? So basically there is no more inline, you have to handle the save related by hand, there is no "add another button", etc... You just loose all the power of the inlines :(

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear, I suggest overriding the inline formsets. I ended up posting a separate answer since I came up with a solution for a project of my own.

Comment: Changing Django code is hardly a solution: you are now bound to that specific version and remember to apply these changes any time you'll decide to upgrade. That's like forking Django project...