# Django admin validate inline formset against field in model

Tags: python, django, admin, inline-formset

I'm currently learning python and django and I got stuck. I have the following models:

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    population = models.IntegerField()

class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

# Represents the election result of a particular Candidate in a particular State
class Result(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
    num_votes = models.IntegerField()
```

My admin.py contains this:

```
class CandidateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name']

class ResultInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        # Check that total number of votes doesn't exceed population
        sum = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            sum += form.cleaned_data.get('num_votes')
            # This is the part where I'm stuck
            if (sum > value_of_population_field_from_State_form):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Total number of votes cannot exceed state population")

class ResultInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Result
    extra = 0
    formset = ResultInlineFormset

class StateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'population']
    inlines = [ResultInline]

admin.site.register(Candidate, CandidateAdmin)
admin.site.register(State, StateAdmin)
```

As you can see, I need to somehow check that the total number of votes (sum of votes for all candidates) is not higher than the state's population. To do that I guess I would need to access the value of the population field in State form but I have no idea how to do that or if it's possible at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation of dependant inlines in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526792/validation-of-dependant-inlines-in-django-admin)