# Add foreign key related entities in the same Django admin page

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-admin

I'm working on a Django app which will manage some quizzes. Those quizzes are formed by a question and some possible answers, which I've defined as different models.

There is an OneToMany relationship between them, which as far as I know, should be modeled with a foreign key, in this case, in the answer entity.

However, while managing the data from the Django administration site, this is quite inconvenient, because I've to define first my question, and later, while adding the answers, look for the question in order to fill the foreign key field.

Would be somehow possible, to define all the answers while adding the question, in a similar way as if it was a ManyToMany relationship (the box with the + symbol, etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) for this.

In your case, this could look something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AnswerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Answer
    extra = 1  # If you have a fixed number number of answers, set it here.

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Question
    inlines = [
        AnswerInline,
    ]

# don't forget to register your model
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

*Hope that helps and happy coding!*

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Just one further question: would be somehow possible checking if there is just one correct answer for each question? I've done something similar with the clean() method in the past.

Comment: @pitazzo. You are very welcome! Yes, you could do that by overwriting the inline formset, I think. Answering this in a comment is not really possible (too short), but maybe this question will help you getting started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526792/validation-of-dependant-inlines-in-django-admin Otherwise I suggest you create a separate question for this.