# How to use admin.TabularInline in a ModelForm

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-admin

full story [Only validate admin form if condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738414/only-validate-admin-form-if-condition-is-true?answertab=active#tab-top)

I am trying to validate that a form has an answer.
In order to validate a form in the admin you need to make a new form and tell the admin.ModelAdmin class to use that form.

Is this correct?

I have created a form but now I can't use my inlines form. If I put it in the admin.ModelAdmin it still shows up and I can still fill that part out but it doesn't appear in the form cleaned_data if though it is in the post data.

How do I use ChoiceInline in QuestionAdminForm?

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 4


#TODO: move?
class QuestionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    choices = ChoiceInline

    class Meta:
        model = Question

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        #logger.info(data)
        choices = self.cleaned_data['choices']
        #logger.info(data)

        if not self.choices_set.filter(
                choice=choices.strip(), is_correct=True).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong choice!")

        # Always return the cleaned data, whether you have changed it or
        # not.
        return data


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('average', 'last_updated')
    #list_display = ["question", "module", "average", "quiz"]
    #can't have below because M2M question-> module
    #list_display = ["question", "module", "average"]
    list_display = ["question", "average"]
    list_display_links = ["question"]
    list_filter = ['modules__name']
    search_fields = ["question", "modules__name", "quiz__name"]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    actions = [duplicate_questions]
    form = QuestionAdminForm
```

Comment: can you not just replace `choices = ChoiceInline` with `choices = forms.CharField()` ?

Comment: that would get me one CharField, I would like it to ideally be just like the inlines. With 4 sets of CharField and checkbox that I can add more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing based on [Django admin validation for inline form which rely on the total of a field between all forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735920/django-admin-validation-for-inline-form-which-rely-on-the-total-of-a-field-betwe)

```
class CombinedFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    # Validate formset data here
    def clean(self):
        super(CombinedFormSet, self).clean()
        for form in self.forms:
            if not hasattr(form, 'cleaned_data'):
                continue

            data = self.cleaned_data
            valid = False
            for i in data:
                if i != {}:
                    if i['is_correct']:
                        valid = True

            if not valid:
                #TODO: translate admin?
                raise forms.ValidationError("A Question must have an answer.")

            # Always return the cleaned data, whether you have changed it or
            # not.
            return data


class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 4
    formset = CombinedFormSet
```