# howto add custom form into django administrator page inlines

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

Can I get a form into Django Administrator page, that I have defined in forms.py?
Can I also get this form into Model inlines of Django Administrator page ?

To be clear, this is what I call inline:

```
class AnswerInline(admin.StackedInline):
  ...
```

Comment: You want to define your own formset, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877723/inline-form-validation-in-django#877920

Comment: Is there a simple resource I can refer to, in order to understand where and How to use forms in general. The Django documentation is a little cryptic to me right now.

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, it's a bit complicated but [the docs are actually clear here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form):

> InlineModelAdmin.form
> The value for form defaults to ModelForm. This is what is passed through to
> inlineformset_factory when creating the formset for this inline.

So create your form class and then refer to it in the inline, like so:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    …

class AnswerInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    form = MyForm
```