# Django - Add form validation to inlineformset_factory

Tags: python, django, formset, inline-formset

So, I'm trying to validate some fields from an inlineformset_factory object, but I don't see how to do that in a clean way from this view (not using a Form class).

Would it be possible to override the .is_valid() method in this case?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
def tenant(request, id):
    tenant = Tenant.objects.get(id=id)

    DealerFormset = inlineformset_factory(Tenant, Dealer, fields=('name', 'phone_number'), extra=0)
    formset = DealerFormset(instance=tenant)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = DealerFormset(request.POST, instance=tenant)
        if formset.is_valid(): # <---  How to add custom validations here?
            formset.save()                

        return redirect('tenant_details', id=tenant.id)

    context = {
        'formset': formset,
    }

    return render(request, 'tenant_details.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `inlineformset_factory` to create the set, I would recommend subclassing `BaseInlineFormSet` and implementing the `clean`method. Once you have a custom `FormSet` class, you can pass that to `inlineformset_factory` via the `formset` keyword argument. The following should work with your current design:

```
from django.forms import (
    BaseInlineFormSet, inlineformset_factory
)

# Make a custom FormSet class and implement the clean method
# to customize the validation
class CustomInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean():
        # Implement your custom validation here

# Use your custom FormSet class as an argument to inlineformset_factory
DealerFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Tenant, Dealer, fields=('name', 'phone_number'),
    extra=0, formset=CustomInlineFormSet
)
```

`DealerFormset` can now be used because it has both basic and custom validations.

Comment: Thank you, will try this in my code and get back with some comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130048/howto-add-custom-form-into-django-administrator-page-inlines

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to create your own formset based on the `BaseInlineFormSet` class. You can take a look at the django doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) for more information but there's nothing really complicated about it.

You would then create the formset by adding the formset to use as a parameter:

```py
formset_factory(TestForm, formset=BaseTestFormSet)
```