# Django Polls App - New poll should have at least two choices

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.x

I recently finished the Django Polls App tutorial.
Now i'm wondering how to force the admin to create at least two choices before he can save a new poll. I would like to make at least two choices required before a save can happen.

Regards,
Robo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harder than it seems! You want to create a custom formset with its own validation, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877723/inline-form-validation-in-django).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I thought it would be much easier with a special model attribute or sth.