# Django - At least one inline formset filled out of multiple different inline formsets

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-validation

is there a way to validate that at least 1 of the many different formsets are not empty inside `forms.py`?

I have a working validation inside `views.py` but this validation don't apply to admin form. I want my code to be DRY and so my idea is to write the validation inside `forms.py`, so that both admin and HTML form share the same validation.

`models.py`, `Person` can have multiple `PersonAddress` and `PersonEmail`. In my actual `models.py`, I have many more related class, not just `PersonAddress`, `PersonEmail`, I just simplify it to 2 to make this example simpler.

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

class PersonAddress(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="person_address",
    )
    ...

class PersonEmail(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="person_email",
    )
    ...
```

`forms.py`, `PersonAddressFormSet` and `PersonEmailFormSet` will become inline formsets of `PersonForm`

```py
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

class PersonAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

class PersonEmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

PersonAddressFormSet = forms.models.inlineformset_factory(
    Person, PersonAddress, form=PersonAddressForm, can_delete=False, extra=1,
)
PersonEmailFormSet = forms.models.inlineformset_factory(
    Person, PersonEmail, form=PersonEmailForm, can_delete=False, extra=1,
)
```

`views.py`, under `form_valid` method, if both address and email formset are not `has_changed`, I will return form error

```py
class PersonCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, MetadataMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Person
    form_class = PersonForm
    template_name = "person/person_form.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PersonCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context["addresses"] = PersonAddressFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
            context["emails"] = PersonEmailFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            context["addresses"] = PersonAddressFormSet()
            context["emails"] = PersonEmailFormSet()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        context = self.get_context_data()
        addresses = context["addresses"]
        emails = context["emails"]
        personfs = [addresses, emails]
        if (
                all(fs.is_valid() for fs in personfs)
        ):
            if not any(fs.has_changed() for fs in personfs):
                form.add_error(
                    None, ValidationError(
                        _("""
                        Please fill up either address / email
                        """)
                    )
                )
                return self.form_invalid(form)
            else:
                self.object = form.save()
                for fs in personfs:
                    fs.instance = self.object
                    fs.save()
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        return super(PersonCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Now, I want the same validation for admin form, through `forms.py`. I thought of using `PersonForm.clean`

```py
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        print(f"PersonForm.clean.cleaned_data: {cleaned_data}")
        return cleaned_data
```

but `PersonAddress` and `PersonEmail` is not found under `cleaned_data` dict. So I am not sure if this is possible?

If my idea of putting validation inside `forms.py` is not possible. Is there a way I can write validation that works on both admin and HTML form?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877723/inline-form-validation-in-django

Comment: @tahamaatof, no, that example is using a single type of formset `InvoiceOrder`, but I have multiple different formsets `PersonAddress` and `PersonEmail`. Also, that method is only for admin form, I want to write validation that I can use on both admin and HTML form :)